# PDO/MYSQL parentheses () in query

Tags: mysql, pdo

Having some issues performing a PDO LIKE Query containing ().

```
<?php

...    

$text_with_parentheses = '%'.$text_with_parentheses.'%'

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE alarm LIKE :alarm');
$sth->bindParam(':alarm' , $text_with_parentheses);
$sth->execute();
$response = $sth->fetch();

...

?>
```

The string value I'm querying is an alarm text, stored in a varchar utf8_uncode_ci column. It Looks like this:

'ABCD. Status ABCD (6): (fail)'

It seems I cannot figure out how to escape the parentheses. Tested both via PHP/PDO and directly in MYSQL console. For testing i tested the follwoing in directly in the MYSQL console

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column`='ABCD. Status ABCD (6): (fail)'
```

It returns 0 results.

The only way to get any results - both in PDO and MYSQL console - is doing:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` LIKE 'ABCD. status ABCD%'
```

But that returns several values which is not viable. When searching for values that does not contain parentheses it works fine.

Anyone have any ideas? This seems like a MYSQL issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parenthesis **have absolutely no meaning** neither in mysql strings nor in PDO.

Your problem is caused by something else.

Select the existing value from database and encode it to see all non-printable characters:

```
echo rawurlencode($value);
```

and then compare.

The genuine `ABCD. Status ABCD (6): (fail)` string will make

```
ABCD.%20Status%20ABCD%20%286%29%3A%20%28fail%29
```

while one from database something different. Compare and check the difference.

Comment: Used rawurlencode($value); in a test page to check input and output. got it to Work.
It seems you are correct (ofcourse ;) ). I better get some sleep and I'll run through the code again tomorrow.

Comment: Figured out that the issue was actually that some of the sent alarms contained doubled quotes (&quot;) and the stored copy comes out as %22 (url encoded).